# Python: Figure out "Spouse" class?

Tags: python, oop, class, multiple-inheritance

So here I have a problem. Let's say I have 2 parent classes. They both inherit from a master class. Then they are both parent classes to a child class. Is there a way to figure out (let's say I'm Father) which Mother class I'm "having a child with?" I don't need the child to figure out which mother class, I want the Father to be able to figure out which mother class it is.

I know this is a silly example, but it's a simplified version of what I have to do elsewhere.

```
class Master(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.troll()
        self.trell()

class Mother1(Master):
    def troll(self):
        print 'troll1'

class Mother2(Master):
    def troll(self):
        print 'troll2'

class Father(Master):
    def trell(self):
        print 'trell'
        print self.figure_out_spouse_class()

class Child1(Mother1, Father):
    pass

class Child2(Mother2, Father):
    pass

c = Child1() #should print 'Mother1'
c = Child2() #should print 'Mother2'
```

~
~
~
~

Comment: Even Python isn't powerful enough to figure out a spouse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `__bases__`:

```
def figure_out_spouse_class(self):
    return [b.__name__ for b in self.__class__.__bases__ if b != Father]
```

(This would return the names of all "spouse" classes if there are more than one).

Comment: @user1137940 -- If this solution works for you (as you've indicated), you should accept it (click the little check-mark next to it).  That gives David a little bonus reputation (and you get a little too).  Also, it allows others who come across this post to immediately see which answer is the best. (+1 from me btw)

Answer (score 1):

You can look at `__bases__` of the class of the child object, something like

```
class Father(Master):
    def trell(self):
        print self.__class__.__bases__[0]
        super(self.__class__, self).troll()
```